# Finding duplicate names where first name can be an initial or full name

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find duplicates by comparing the first name and surname columns in a table. The first name can be a name or an initial.

Reading other posts I have managed to figure out how to get the duplicate surnames and list the first letter for first name. But I am unsure how to only show rows where there is a match of surname and the first letter of the first name.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table AS a
INNER JOIN (

SELECT LEFT( firstname, 1 ) , surname
FROM table
GROUP BY surname
HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1
) AS b ON a.surname = b.surname

id | firstname | surname
**************************
1  | joe       | bloggs
2  | j         | bloggs
3  | s         | bloggs
4  | f         | doe
5  | frank     | spencer
```

Currently this query would return

```
1  | joe       | bloggs
2  | j         | bloggs
3  | s         | bloggs
```

Result I would like would just contain the possible duplicates.

```
1  | joe       | bloggs
2  | j         | bloggs
```

Comment: When asking SQL questions, you should provide some sample data from the tables and an example of what you're hoping the output will look like.

Comment: Thanks for the input, have added some, not sure if thats enough to clarify what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite get what you want. Yor provided a query, your current table and the expected result.

I've just created your table, run your query and got the expected result. What is wrong with this?

```
SELECT  FROM table1 AS a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT surname FROM table1
  GROUP BY surname
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS b ON a.surname = b.surname
```

This effectively result in your expected result:

```
joe | bloggs
j   | bloggs
```

Or am I missing something?

After re-reading... are you expecting to get only this?

```
j | bloggs
```

If that is the case, use this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 AS a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT surname FROM table1
  GROUP BY surname
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS b ON a.surname = b.surname
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(firstname) = 1
```

**Edit:**

After the expected result was properly explained I conclude the query should be:

```
SELECT a.firstname, a.surname FROM t1 AS a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT LEFT(firstname, 1) AS firstChar, surname FROM t1
  GROUP BY surname, firstChar
  HAVING COUNT(surname) > 1
) AS b ON a.surname = b.surname AND b.firstChar = LEFT(a.firstname, 1)
```

Working [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c01c1/13)

Comment: Ahh sorry I did a late night edit, missed out that it currently returns some one with the same last name but different first names which is obviously not a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks alot, just what I was after, I guess being lazy and using * was why some of the stuff I tried did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to use initials all the time, e.g., if you always strip to initials you might consider Bob X the same as Bill X. 
So you need to check three cases.

1. both firstnames are initials
2. both firstnames are non initials
3. only one firstname is an intial

So you can work with string methods of Mysql to check the length of either firstname and check the proper case.

Comment: Thanks stryba, I think that might be a bit beyond my comfort zone with mysql. But will look into the string functions see if I can  do what you said.

Answer (score 0):

I would join the table to itself like so:

select * into #temp from (
SELECT 1, 'joe', 'bloggs' UNION
SELECT 2, 'j', 'bloggs' UNION
SELECT 3, 'f', 'doe' UNION
SELECT 4, 'frank', 'spencer' UNION
SELECT 5, 'steven', 'woo' UNION
SELECT 6, 'steve', 'woo' UNION
SELECT 7, 'stanley', 'woo' 
) x (id, firstname, surname)

select
    *
from
    #temp l
inner join
    #temp r
on
    left(l.firstname, 1) = left(r.firstname, 1)
and
    l.surname = r.surname
where
    l.id < r.id

drop table #temp

the downside to this is that the steven and stanley match.  I would suggest you think about creating a firstname alias table and use that to standardize the firstnames.